# How to create MongoDB update with multiple conditionals?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'll explain here what I need to do and see if someone can give me a direction about what to look for.

I have a collection "books".
Each book have those fields: id, active, code, title and author and lastUpdated.

I need to set active to false for all books that:
- have same title
- AND have same author 
- AND active is true
- AND have different codes
- AND lastUpdate is older

So let say I have 2 books with different codes (one have code 3, the other have code 4), and different lastUpdated (one have Sep 5, 2018, the other have Aug 5, 2018). All the other fields are the same and active is true for both of them.

After the update I need just onde of them to be active, which will be the one with lastUpdated Aug 5. So the most recent should remain active true and the older one should be updated to active false.

Is there a way in MongoDB to create this query to run all at once with all those conditions?

Comment: Could you please post your data set?